# CSS - transform:scale issues in Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to recreate this [codepen](https://codepen.io/MikeWhitehead/pen/BJyZay) transform:scale transition for a particular page on my site. It works fine on Firefox but it's not working as it should on either Chrome or Safari. On these platforms the image transforms okay but then snaps/jerks back after the allotted timescale (in this case one second) has elapsed. I'm led to believe this might be a common bug for this style rule but I've not been able to find a solution. I can't really change the images from `<img>` to a background-image structure at this stage.

I've recreated the issue with this code snippet -

```css
/* Partners page */

.masonry {
  /* Masonry container */
  column-count: 5;
}

.brick img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Gotham-Light';
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 3em auto;
}

.masonry {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.brick {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Image words / text hover effect */

.brick {
  opacity: .99;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .brick .details {
  padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .7s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .9), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.wrapper .brick:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.brick:hover .details {
  opacity: 1;
}

.brick .details span {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  /* 100px */
  -webkit-transition-property: top, opacity;
  transition-property: top, opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.brick .details #title {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.brick .details #info {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.brick:focus:before,
.brick:focus span,
.brick:hover:before,
.brick:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.brick:focus:before,
.brick:hover:before {
  top: 0;
  /* 50% */
}

.brick:focus span,
.brick:hover span {
  top: 0;
}

.brick:focus #title,
.brick:hover #title {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.brick:focus #info,
.brick:hover #info {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}


/* -------------------------   */
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="masonry">
    <div class="partner">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509810535/Certo-120x72_hrw5eq.png" style="width: 180px; height: 120px;" class="partimg"></a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449086/2brand_identity_oo9udc.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449086/2brand_identity_oo9udc.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449069/2print_zszssh.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449077/2graphic_design_obcmif.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brick"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/mrmw1974/image/upload/v1509449086/2brand_identity_oo9udc.jpg">
      <div class="details">

        <span id="info">Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna, Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. Quisque vel felis lectus donec vitae dapibus magna. </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: I’m getting a bug(?) on mobile safari where the text jumps out of your wrapper div and takes over part of the page. What is the intended design? 

Side note, is this site going to be mobile optimized? You might want to consider another solution that works on both desktop and mobile as the pseudo class for hover is very inconsistent on mobile browers–the UX isn’t great.

Comment: @JDP It doesn’t need to work on a mobile , is there not a media query I can use to make this work only on screen sizes above 960px?

Comment: this seems familiar to me :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, it's along the lines of something I posted about a month ago but different because this question is focused on an issue in chrome/safari :)

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead – You can definitely use a media query, but you might run into issues with larger tablets still. Best practice I use is that anytime you’re hiding and revealing content with hover you should have a mobile fallback as well – Just to ensure all users are able to access your content. Unless you plan on blocking all phone/tablet traffic you may want to investigate an alternative treatment.